# Field $K = F_2[X]/(X^6 +X + 1)$: Show that $a^9 = a^4 + a^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Could someone steer me in the right direction on how to solve questions like these? Or anything I could read/watch to help me solve these kind of questions?

I have studied up on fields and know roughly what they are. I know that they're closed under addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

We have a Field $K = F_2[X]/(X^6 +X + 1)$

$a$ is the class of $X$ in $K$

Show that $a^9 = a^4 + a^3$

Comment: $a^9+a^4+a^3$ is divided by $a^6+a+1$. Also, $-1=1$ in $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thanks but I would love to get a more thorough explanation on this. I'm still not sure what's going on exactly.

Comment: You need to start utilizing mathjax when you post questions, SJ19.

Comment: See [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The answerers got it right. You could also do the following. You know that $a^6+a+1=0$. Therefore $a^6=-a^6=a+1$. Therefore $a^7=a\cdot a^6=a(a+1)=a^2+a$. Thereforet $a^8=a(a^7)=a(a^2+a)=a^3+a^2$. Therefore...? There will be more terms, when the exponent gets higher, but as long as you remember that $(1+1)=0$ and $1=-1$ in the field $K$ you will do fine.

Comment: If you think you need more exercises on this type of problems, try and reproduce the tables [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619) that I prepared for referrals like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly we have $a^6+a+1=0$ by construction. Since in $\Bbb F_2$ we have $1+1=0$, it implies $f+f=0$ for any polynomial $f\in\Bbb F_2[X]$. Then adding $a+1$ to both sides yields
$$a^6=a+1$$
Then just multiply it by $a^3$.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'm missing some fundemental knowledge on this. If you don't mind could you explain more about how classes works? The meaning of "a" especially.

Comment: We quotient out by the equivalence relation for which $f\sim g$ iff $g-f$ is in the given ideal $(X^6+X+1)$, that is, if $g-f$ is a multiple of $X^6+X+1$. Thus, in particular $X^6+X+1\sim 0$. $a$ is the equivalence class of $X$. Taking the quotient can also be thought as simply regarding equals the equivalents, basically replacing $\sim$ in the ambient set to $=$ in the quotient set. Because we work with an ideal, all the ring operations are well defined in the quotient set.

Answer (score 2):

We have to show that $a^9=a^4+a^3$. $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^6+x+1)$ is the field of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2$ (in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the possible coefficients of polynomials are $0$ and $1$) modulo the ideal $(x^6+x+1):=\{p(x)(x^6+x+1)|p(x) \in \mathbb{F_2}[x]\}$.

Now take $a^9$ divided by $a^6+a+1$.
This gives you : $$a^9=a^4+a^3+a^3(a^6+a+1)\equiv_{\mathbb{K}}a^4+a^3$$